# Run two functions in parallel in pathos

Tags: python, pathos

I have 2 different functions, let's say:

```
def foo(print_me):   
    print(print_me + " foo")

def foo2(print_me):   
    print(print_me + " foo2")
```

I want to run them both, parallel, in pathos.

in multiprocessing I will do something like:

```
process = [Process(target=foo, args=("HI")),Process(target=foo2, args=("HI2")]
map(lambda p: p.start(), process)
map(lambda p: p.join(), process)
```

How can I do something similar in pathos?

P.S
I can't use python multiprocessing because in the real functions, I am using `spacy` which can't use multiprocessing (due to the pickle error).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
>>> def foo(print_me):   
...     print(print_me + " foo")
... 
>>> def foo2(print_me):   
...     print(print_me + " foo2")
... 
>>> from pathos.helpers import mp
>>> process = [mp.Process(target=foo, args=("HI",)),mp.Process(target=foo2, args=("HI2",))]
>>> r1 = map(lambda p: p.start(), process) 
>>> r2 = map(lambda p: p.join(), process) 
>>> r1 = list(r1); r1 = list(r2)
HI foo
HI2 foo2
>>>
```

I also corrected the typos in your code above, but not in your question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What version is this? I work on python 3.6 on the latest version. I don't have 'mp' but only 'mp_helper' and it doesn't find Process.

Comment: I'm using the most current version from GitHub ( '0.2.4.dev0').  It has `mp_helper` and `mp`.

Comment: You are right, I looked for it way too much time. thank you